# When editing item from table, it pulls/saves the wrong information

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, ejs

So, I am working on a CRUD application and I am trying to make it so that I can edit the project when I click edit. I can successfully get the project ID with the req.params.id and it is successfully printing the correct information into the console but when I go to send it to my front end it is still updating the information for the first entry in the collection. Below is the code that I used for this. 
Backend:

```
router.get('/edit/(:id)', function (req, res, next) {
   var o_id = new ObjectId(req.params.id).toString();

   db.collection('projects').find({
     "_id": ObjectId(o_id).toString
   }).toArray(function (err, result) {
     if (err) return console.log(err)

     // if user not found
     if (!result) {
       req.flash('error', 'Project not found with id = ' + req.params.id)
       res.redirect('/projects')
     } else { // if user found
       console.log(result);
       // render to views/user/edit.ejs template file
       res.render('edit.ejs', {
         user: req.user,
         title: 'Edit User',
         //data: rows[0],
         projID: result[0]._id,
         projName: result[0].projectName,
         projStat: result[0].status,
         projEngineer: result[0].engineer,
         projCost: result[0].finalCost
       });
     }
   });
 });
```

Frontend for listing the projects:

```
<tbody>
  <form action="/edit/<%=projID%>" method="post" class="d-flex align-self-center mx-auto" style="width:500px;height:500px;padding:0px;margin:0px;background-color:rgb(255,255,255);">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="projName" value="<%=projName %>">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="projStat" value="<%=projStat %>">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="projEngineer" value="<%=projEngineer %>">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="projCost" value="<%=projCost %>">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" style="background-color:rgb(4,148,74);">Submit</button>
  </form>
</tbody>
```

Front end for editing

```
<tbody>
  <form action="/edit/<%=projID%>" method="post" class="d-flex align-self-center mx-auto" style="width:500px;height:500px;padding:0px;margin:0px;background-color:rgb(255,255,255);">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="projName" value="<%=projName %>">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="projStat" value="<%=projStat %>">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="projEngineer" value="<%=projEngineer %>">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="projCost" value="<%=projCost %>">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" style="background-color:rgb(4,148,74);">Submit</button>
  </form>
</tbody>
```

Comment: have you tried clearing the browser cache?

Comment: check if you get more than 1 result.

Comment: @AndreiNikolaenko yeah just did that and that is my issue. Apparently, something is wrong with my query.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out my issue, the way I was querying the db returned all of the objects, I just had to loop over it and find where the id matches up. Thanks to @andreiNikolaenko for pointing out to check that.

Comment: It shouldn't return more than one document since you're querying by ID.